# Does "review over" mean go through every keywords in the context of classroom?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

A kindergarten teacher starts her lesson with

> To help us to **review over** antonyms, we're going to do an antonym rap. I want you to move from side to side, all right? Are you ready?

Let's say they've learned 5 pairs of antonyms previously, does **review over** here mean "they will go through each of those 5 pairs"?

Comment: In BrE we don't use "review over". We would use the word "revise", meaning "to study again". Before exams we do revision. I don't think this word is used the same way in the US though.

Comment: "study again in a way like learn the contents first time" or "in a different way, usually more fast"?

Comment: The second. Revising is quicker than learning. As I said, we revise before exams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct ways to say this:

- review antonyms
- go over antonyms again (as a review)

"review over" seems like a mash-up of those two expressions. Certainly it makes sense. The question is whether it's 100% officially correct English, or more on the spectrum of informal/colloquial.  I'd tend towards the latter.

> does review over here mean "they will go through each of those 5 pairs"?

Usually reviewing is quicker than studying, and not the same level of depth. You review before an exam to refresh your memory.

In this very specific case though, if there are "5 pairs of antonyms", reviewing will probably mean looking at *all* the pairs again. There won't be much difference between studying and reviewing.